# JQWidgets: JqxNumberInput setting editor value to null

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, jqwidget

I am using jqxNumberInput as an numeric editor for my web application in a web user control. I would like to set the default value of the editor to be null. Currently it shows up with a zero in it. jqxNumberInput doesn't support a null value itself. Is there a way to remove that zero using javascript, jquery, or in the codefile of my vb.net web application?

I am using the current version of JQWidgets, Visual 2012, .Net Framework 4.

Here is my script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#test").jqxNumberInput({ width: "<%=m_sWidth%>", height: "<%=m_sHeight%>", inputMode: "<%=m_sInputMode%>", decimalDigits: "<%=m_iDecimalDigits%>" });
    $("#test").setDecimal('');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you want to initialize your jqxNumberInput with nothing in.

Here is a solution :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test").jqxNumberInput({
                width: "<%=m_sWidth%>",
                height: "<%=m_sHeight%>",
                inputMode: "<%=m_sInputMode%>",
                decimalDigits: "<%=m_iDecimalDigits%>"
            });
            $("#test input").val('');
        });
```

The instruction `$("#test input").val('');` is going to get the input used by jqxNumberInput directly in the DOM and clear it